# Configure Karate Mock to work with API's having Content Type other than JSON, XML

Tags: karate

I need to mock an API using Karate Mock which accepts messages with Content-Type as below and respond accordingly

```
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

I tried to configure it in feature file as below but encountered below issue. I guess by default it is accepting JSON as the content-type, Is there any way to configure mock to read custom messages like this one.

**Actual API call:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"    -d "elem_value=generic_value&address="  http://myhost:9090/api/resource_path
```

**Mock feature file:**

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/api/resource_path') && typeContains('urlencoded') 
        * def responseStatus = 200
        * def response = read ('/payload/Success.json')
        * print response
```

**Actual Error:**

```
Caused by: <eval>:1 ReferenceError: "generic_value" is not defined
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:319)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:291)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.__noSuchProperty__(Global.java:1441)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$43$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:449)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should have been fixed in a newer version of Karate, please try upgrade.

I think it will be in 0.9.2 - https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/649

Comment: This worked fine in 0.9.2, Thank you. But, json file read is failed in this version(same used to work in previous version) with below error. Is there any change in the way file is read in latest version?                                                                                           could not find or read file: /payload/Success.json                                                       As a workaround, i have placed the json content in feature file itself and made it work for now